# qtree and babel - escaping character no caught

Tags: babel, qtree

I started using the package `qtree` to draw (simple) trees with LaTeX
This package uses the `!` to escape some commands/macros.

I tried framing part of the tree, copy/pasting the example in the documentation, but because of babel, loaded with french option, the `!` is not caught and interpreted as a new leaf.

M(not)WE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{report}
\usepackage[french]{babel}    % no problems with [english], [greek, english], [german]
\usepackage{qtree}
\begin{document}
  \Tree [.IP [.NP Roses ] [ [.I^0 are ]
    [.VP t [ [.V^0 turning ] [.NP pink ] ] ].VP !{\qframesubtree} ]]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\shorthandoff{!}` before the `\Tree` and `\shorthandon{!}` after it.

Comment: Exactly right as usual, thanks a lot! Is it because in french a spacing is needed before the exclamation mark, hence it must be redefined in babel? (I thought about that but didn't know the shorthandoff/on commands, now I do :) ) Could you make it an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to disable `!` as a shorthand:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{report}
\usepackage[french]{babel}    
\usepackage{qtree}
\begin{document}
\shorthandoff{!}
  \Tree [.IP [.NP Roses ] [ [.I^0 are ]
    [.VP t [ [.V^0 turning ] [.NP pink ] ] ].VP !{\qframesubtree} ]]
\shorthandon{!}
\end{document}
```

[image]